# Has Trump expressed any opinion about US allies like Germany, Japan, or South Korea getting their own nuclear weapons?

Tags: donald-trump, nuclear-weapons, western-world

Opinion in other US allies may be lowers on this, [but](https://www.voanews.com/a/as-trump-looms-south-koreans-mull-their-own-nukes/6848246.html)

> A poll published in May by the conservative Asan Institute for Policy Studies suggested that more than 70% of South Koreans support their country developing indigenous nuclear weapons -- the highest level of support since the organization began asking the question in 2010.
>
> [...] Although South Korea is protected by the U.S. nuclear umbrella, some South Korean analysts believe the United States may be reluctant to respond to a North Korean attack if Pyongyang has the ability to destroy a major U.S. city -- in essence, the fear is that the United States would not want to risk San Francisco to save Seoul.

Trump has called for all US allies to become much more self-sufficient in defense. But many adversaries have nuclear weapons, while many US allies (except France, the UK, and unofficially Israel) do not. (Can't recall if India is officially listed as a US ally.) Has Trump said anything about other US allies getting their own nuclear weapons programs?

Comment: When Trump was President of the USA, the USA was a signatory to the NPT...

Comment: India is not a US ally, unofficially or otherwise. Why would you think that's the case? Pakistan (India's closest regional adversary) is within the US sphere of influence.

Comment: @uberhaxed: Pakistan is far more in China's boat these days. And 'In 2016, the United States recognized India as a "major defense partner"'--whatever that means. They even admitted it's a "status unique to India". https://dod.defense.gov/Portals/1/Documents/pubs/NDAA-India-Joint-Report-FY-July-2017.pdf

Comment: And India is also not aligned with China for the same reason.

Comment: @uberhaxed: you're right though that Pak is still on paper a 'major ally' of the US. But recent governments there essentially deny that, making the US claims increasingly look like wishful thinking. https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2023/09/27/kakar-pakistan-us-china-ukraine/

Comment: I read a list of countries which would have the technology to build nuclear weapons right now, and Germany, Japan and South Korea are on that list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Trump has suggested that US allies should acquire nuclear weapons, particularly in cases where the US has given a one-sided commitment to defend nations (Japan, South Korea), but not with respect to NATO members like Germany.

In March 2016, while campaigning for his first term in office, Trump did suggest that some of America's allies such as Japan and South Korea might get nuclear weapons, to even out the playing field when many of the US's adversaries and its allies' adversaries (North Korea, China) already have nuclear weapons. ([CBS News report](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/donald-trump-japan-south-korea-might-need-nuclear-weapons/))

He was quoted at a Town Hall meeting in Milwaukee as saying

> You have so many countries already -- China, Pakistan, you have so many countries, Russia -- you have so many countries right now that have them. .... Now, wouldn't you rather, in a certain sense, have Japan have nuclear weapons when North Korea has nuclear weapons?

Citing the cost of defending America's allies, he suggested a change in nuclear policy:

> Maybe it's going to have to be time to change, because so many people -- you have Pakistan has it, you have China has it. You have so many other countries are now having it.

He also made similar comments to the New York Times around the same time (quoted by [CBS](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/donald-trump-america-first-vision-world-election-2016/)), citing the current situation where the US promises to defend Japan but Japan does not promise to defend the US, and suggesting alternatives:

> Unfortunately, we have a nuclear world now. Would I rather have North Korea have [nuclear weapons] with Japan sitting there having them also? You may very well be better off if that's the case. In other words, where Japan is defending itself against North Korea, which is a real problem.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. I'm guessing none of that was followed through by President Trump though. I did find a [Nikkei piece from 2020](https://asia.nikkei.com/Spotlight/Comment/Trump-demands-Japan-and-South-Korea-pay-for-nuclear-umbrella) saying he asked for payment for the US nuclear umbrella, so I guess there's that.

Comment: "The Trump administration is demanding that South Korea cover not only the cost of the U.S. military presence, but part of the cost of the U.S. nuclear and conventional weapons used to defend the country, according to multiple diplomatic sources." I guess that was all behind closed doors.

Comment: As for those quotes you gave, it looks like a bit later he denied he implied that those countries should get nukes https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2016/nov/14/donald-trump/donald-trump-wrongly-tweets-he-never-said-more-cou/